# Adding label to frame class via method from another class in tkinter 0

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am attempting to adjust my tkinter code into an OOP approach. So far, the framework is created but now am snagged on interaction between the classes. The submit_name function of the HelloWorld class is accessed by the submit button command in the InputFrame, but I am not sure how to take what was in the entry of the InputFrame and radio button selection then place that text into a new label of the OutputFrame. Any suggestions or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Here is the working function in my non-OOP Code:

```
def submit_name():
    '''prints out message based on text and radio button selection'''
    if case_style.get() == 'normal':
        name_label = tk.Label(output_frame, text='Hello ' + name.get() + '! Keep on learning Tkinter!', bg=output_color)
    elif case_style.get() == 'upper':
        name_label = tk.Label(output_frame, text=('Hello ' + name.get() + '! Keep on learning Tkinter!').upper(), bg=output_color)
    name_label.pack()
    name.delete(0, END)
```

OOP Code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,StringVar, END

class HelloWorld(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Hello, World!")
        self.geometry('400x400')
        self.resizable(0,0)
        self_color = '#224870'
        self.config(bg=self_color)
        
        InputFrame(self).pack(pady=10)
        OutputFrame(self).pack(padx=10, pady=(0,10),fill='both',expand=True)        
    def submit_name(self):
        '''adjusts text case in entry widget based on radio button selection and prints to OutputFrame'''
        pass

class InputFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container,*args, **kwargs)
        self.case_style=StringVar()
        self.case_style.set('normal')
        self.input_color = '#2a4494'
        self.config(bg=self.input_color)
        self.name=tk.Entry(self, width=20)
        self.name.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        submit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Submit', command=container.submit_name)
        submit_button.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=20)
        normal_button = tk.Radiobutton(self, text='Normal Case',variable=self.case_style,value='normal',bg=self.input_color)
        normal_button.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=2, pady=2)
        upper_button = tk.Radiobutton(self, text='Upper Case',variable=self.case_style,value='upper',bg=self.input_color)
        upper_button.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
        

        
class OutputFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,container,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(container,*args,**kwargs)
        self.output_color = '#4ea5da'
        self.config(bg=self.output_color)

root = HelloWorld()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you create the Frame objects, but then you throw out the reference to them so you can't use them again. You need to change your code to keep that reference, and then you can access them from anywhere.

```
class HelloWorld(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Hello, World!")
        self.geometry('400x400')
        self.resizable(0,0)
        self_color = '#224870'
        self.config(bg=self_color)
        
        self.input_frame = InputFrame(self)
        self.input_frame.pack(pady=10)
        self.output_frame = OutputFrame(self)
        self.output_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=(0,10),fill='both',expand=True)  
      
    def submit_name(self):
        '''adjusts text case in entry widget based on radio button selection and prints to OutputFrame'''
        data = self.input_frame.name.get()
        self.output_frame.output_label.config(text=data)
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver!! This makes complete sense now and was able to transfer the function code seamlessly. Thank you again.